# Scrape Download Url from a link generated by javascript

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I know this post will probably be closed, but I have to try because I am very desperate.
I am not looking for a solution but for a technique.
I try to scrape some content from a public site (I am doing it with beautiful soap in python but it doesn't matter).
I have stumbled into a problem getting a download link.
consider this:

```
<a href="/games/9380-beach-buggy-racing/download-filelocal-55787" class="onclick-download-ads app-btn cuprum" title="Скачать apk файл, размером 90.0 MB">
    <b class="btntext">Скачать</b>
    <span class="lcol">90.0 MB</span>
    <span class="rcol">(apk)</span>

</a>
```

this download link when pressed download a file from this address -

```
http://dl3.top-android.org/?a=eyJkYXRhIjp7ImluZm8iOiJXaW5kb3dzOkNocm9tZXw4OS4xMzguNTQuMjIwIiwiZGF0YSI6eyJpc19hdXRoZW50aWNhdGVkIjpmYWxzZSwiZmlsZW5hbWUiOiJhcHBsaWNhdGlvbnMvYmVhY2gtYnVnZ3ktcmFjaW5nLTEuMi4xMi5hcGsifX19%3A1df1Gg%3AbsYoAragbQaUlQ_hjhJHL3FEliI%3A1df1Gg%3ATE9B8n9tJuMAKwBuzd1hXZmMOaA
```

As you can see this is not the href address in the a tag.
I want to get somehow this link.

1. I know the browser doesn't make any new requests (monitored it via developer tab) when I press this link.
2. I tried to search all the js files and found nothing related to dl3.top...

please help me understand what is going on.
As I understand if no request is being made I already have all the relevant information loaded in my browser.

Comment: maybe a HTTP redirect? what happens if you type the href address (with the original host name) on the browser or, better yet, in curl?

Comment: also, if you `decodeURIComponent` and then base64-decode the href of the latest link, you get `{"data":{"info":"Windows:Chrome|89.138.54.220","data":{"is_authenticated":false,"filename":"applications/beach-buggy-racing-1.2.12.apk"}}}` ... dont know if it helps !

Comment: first of all yes Its a clue! very cool! but when I try to decode it in python I get an error : Incorrect padding. Do you have any idia why? this you decode only what comes after ?a= or all the url?

Comment: first decode as uri component, then you'll see it has 3 parts separated by ":", the base64-encoded json is the first one until the first ":", the other 2 things are values

Comment: and we don't know anything about those values? I guess they are the key to the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know the browser doesn't make any new requests (monitored it via
>   developer tab) when I press this link.

The browser actually does make a new request; and it responds with `HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND` with a `Location` header containing the URL you seek.

[image: Download link response headers]

Here is a simple script to scrape that `Location` header from this URL. You'll have to add `User-Agent` and `Referer` headers in order to get a valid response, otherwise the response will be a `403 Forbidden` error.

**Python 3 code**

```
import http.client
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("top-android.org")
conn.debuglevel = 1
conn.request("GET","/games/1556-pou-tamago4i/download-filelocal-32318",headers={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0',
    'Referer':'http://top-android.org/games/1556-pou-tamago4i/'
    })
r1 = conn.getresponse()

print("\n\nURL: %s" % r1.getheader('Location'))
```

and it will print the wanted link of course:

**Result**

```
> python scrape_location.py
send: b'GET /games/1556-pou-tamago4i/download-filelocal-32318 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: top-android.org\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0\r\nReferer: http://top-android.org/games/1556-pou-tamago4i/\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND\r\n'
header: Date header: Content-Type header: Transfer-Encoding header: Connection header: Set-Cookie header: Vary header: Location header: X-Frame-Options header: Server header: CF-RAY

URL: http://dl3.top-android.org/?a=eyJkYXRhIjp7ImluZm8iOiJXaW5kb3dzOkZpcmVmb3h8MmEwMjo1ODc6OWMyNzplNDAwOjg0OGQ6MmNhOmE4Mjk6MjExNyIsImRhdGEiOnsiaXNfYXV0aGVudGljYXRlZCI6ZmFsc2UsImZpbGVuYW1lIjoiYXBwbGljYXRpb25zL3BvdS10YW1hZ280aS0xLjQuNjYuYXBrIn19fQ%3A1dgoCA%3AFsWjvbE-s3Mqe9tZNS2CAbfUinw%3A1dgoCA%3A6rJ8th0GeOHsVtKeAPpnwNfqUa0
```

Just remember, the `Referer` header must be set to `window.location.href` else will result in a `403` error.

**EDIT**

As [rupps's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45573581/scrape-download-url-from-a-link-generated-by-javascript/45658493?noredirect=1#comment78106791_45573581) explains, that URL contains base64 JSON and binary data. In my case, the JSON data contains `"is_authenticated":false`:

```
{
    "data": {
        "info": "Windows:Firefox|xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx",
        "data": {
            "is_authenticated": false,
            "filename": "applications/pou-tamago4i-1.4.66.apk"
        }
    }
}
```

which downloads the file as well; it just sometimes fail with a 404 strange error. If I insist hitting the download button it downloads the apk file!

Comment: ohh that's looks promising cant wait to get home and try it out ! :-)

Comment: thanks thats it, but as I can understand I cant change browser for example and go to this link because of the encrypted hash in the url how can I decrypt it ?

Comment: @misha312 you can change the browser and force it to download the file by setting the `window.location.href = "http://dl3.top-android.org/?a=eyJk..."`, but in my side here, most times got 404 errors and after some retries I was able to get thew download to initiate. Maybe that's a server limitation or something that does not happen so often. I suggest you experiment with it and try to make some direct downloads by using the `window.location.href` using javascript AJAX call to that python script.

Answer (score 0):

Search the loaded JS libraries for where an onclick handler is defined for app-btn.
That will show you the handler code that adds the hostname prefix and the "-1.2.12.apk" suffix.